# The verb that describes the movement of your feet

Tags: verbs

I can't find a proper verb to describe the movement of your feet when you slip on an icy surface, then your feet go in "opposite" directions and you lose your balance, because your feet...apart.I thought of "slide apart" but couldn't find it in any reliable source. Thanks.

Comment: Slide sideways?

Comment: It's not your feet, it's your legs. How about "[do the splits](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9856/the-splits-vs-a-split)"?

Comment: We also say "His feet went out from under him".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feet can either

> slide apart

or

> split apart

it depends how quickly it happens.

"Sliding apart" can be slowly and gradually to fairly quick, but "split apart" is instantaneously.

Comment: Are "feet", or "legs"(or both) used? Thanks.

Comment: Feet "slide apart", feet or legs can "split apart".